# Java Array Loop Graphics page not functioning

Tags: java, arrays, swing, oop, user-interface

edit 2: I decided that it would be easier to understand if I just put the entire code up, so that you can test it.

edit: I realize that what I said was unclear, so I will explain this as best as I can. Basically, I am drawing rectangles on a Graphics page using the fillRect method. The problem is that when I change the size of one, they all change, as they are all being redrawn everytime a new one is drawn. To correct this, I added an array that stores all of the sizes which are input via the scrollwheel in another part of the problem. Anyways, I know that the problem is isolated to the loop that supposedly draws them all a certain size, so I added a loop that in theory should give me a temporary variable each time to use that redraws all of the rectangle's sizes starting at 0 each time the main loop is run. The problem is that this does not in fact redraw the rectangles to their individual sizes, and instead draws them to the current size. I have updated the code part as well.

I am having trouble with a project in Java. What it is supposed to do is change the size of each individual rectangle object by storing it in an array, and then recreating the rectangles based off the length from the array. I (at least I think) do this by creating a variable that should be equal to the SIZE that is changed in another part of the program, and then set that equal to the particular element in the array at i. Anyhow, when I do this, I change all of the lengths to whatever the current length is when I draw a rectangle. I know that the problem is by me using i in the size part, but what would I use? Thanks in advance for any help!

Here is the code:

```
public class Dots
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Array Rectangles");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  DotsPanel dotsPanel = new DotsPanel();
  frame.getContentPane().add(dotsPanel);

  //buttons
  JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("RED");
  btnNewButton.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
  btnNewButton.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
  btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    }
  });
  btnNewButton.setForeground(Color.RED);
  dotsPanel.add(btnNewButton);

  JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("GREEN");
  btnNewButton_1.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
  btnNewButton_1.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
  dotsPanel.add(btnNewButton_1);

  JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("BLUE");
  btnNewButton_2.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
  dotsPanel.add(btnNewButton_2);

  JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("BLACK");
  btnNewButton_3.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
  dotsPanel.add(btnNewButton_3);


  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
  }



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DotsPanel extends JPanel
{
// radius of each dot
private int SIZE = 25;  
private int SIZEAccess;

private static final Random generator = new Random();

//used to count amount of dots
private ArrayList<Point> pointList;

int[] sizes = new int [10000];


//Sets up this std. sized panel to listen for mouse events.
public DotsPanel()
{
    pointList = new ArrayList<Point>();

    addMouseListener (new DotsListener());
    addMouseMotionListener(new DotsListener());
    addMouseWheelListener(new DotsListener());

    setBackground(Color.white);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));
}


//used to generate a random color
public static Color randomColor() {
    return new Color(generator.nextInt(256), generator.nextInt(256), generator.nextInt(256));
}

//  Draws all of the dots stored in the list.
public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent(page);

    //draws a centered dot of random color
    int i = 0;
    for (Point spot : pointList)
    {
        sizes[i] = SIZE;
        //SIZEAccess = SIZE;
        //sizes[i] = SIZEAccess;
        //page.fillRect(spot.x-SIZE, spot.y-SIZE, SIZE*2, SIZE*2);
        for (int temp = 0; temp <= i; temp++)
            page.fillRect(spot.x-sizes[temp], spot.y-sizes[temp], sizes[temp]*2, sizes[temp]*2);
        //page.fillRect(spot.x-SIZE, spot.y-SIZE, SIZE*2, SIZE*2);
        //page.setColor(randomColor());

        //page.setColor(c)
        i++;

    }

    //displays the amount of rectangles drawn at the top left of screen
    page.drawString("Count: " + pointList.size(), 5, 15);

    page.drawString("To change the size of the squares, use mouse scroll wheel.", 350, 15);

    page.drawString("Size: " + SIZE, 950, 15);

}

//  Represents the listener for mouse events.
private class DotsListener implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener
{

    //  Adds the current point to the list of points and redraws
    //  the panel whenever the mouse button is pressed.

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
    {
        pointList.add(event.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }


    //  Provide empty definitions for unused event methods.

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {

    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {

    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {

    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}


    //  Adds the current point to the list of points and redraws
    //  the panel whenever the mouse button is dragged.
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        pointList.add(event.getPoint());
        repaint();

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {

    }


    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent event)
    { 
        int notches = 0;
        notches = event.getWheelRotation();
        //int 

        if (notches > 0)
        {
            SIZE = SIZE + notches;
            notches = 0;
        }
        else if (notches < 0)
        {
            int tempSIZE = SIZE;
            tempSIZE = tempSIZE + notches;
            //prevents the program from having dots that increase due to multiplying negatives by negatives 
            //by making anything less than 1 equal 1
            if(tempSIZE < 1)
                tempSIZE = 1;
            SIZE = tempSIZE;
            notches = 0;

        }
    }
}




//SIZE = SIZE + notches;

}
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an animation? I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. If an animation, then use a Swing Timer, not a for loop.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation wasn't great; this is not an animation. It is a program that draws rectangles when the MouseEvent is triggered.

Comment: Please consider editing your question with the goal of trying to make your question as clear as possible. Try to explain your problem as if you were explaining this to a 6 year old. Assume that we know nothing of your current project, desires or problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have ArrayList's interacting with arrays in a confusing mix that makes it hard for us to follow your logic. This suggests that your logic may be too complex for your own good and that your code might benefit from simplification. Why not instead create a `List<Rectangle>` such as an `ArrayList<Rectangle>`, and then simply loop through this list in your paintComponent method, and draw each Rectangle using the Graphics2D object's `draw(...)` or `fill(...)` method:

```
private List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangleList) {
      g2.fill(rectangle);
   }
}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Foo extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private static final Color BACKGROUND = Color.black;
   private static final Color FILL_COLOR = Color.pink;
   private static final Color DRAW_COLOR = Color.red;
   private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(3);
   private List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<>();
   private Point pressPoint = null;
   private Point dragPoint = null;

   public Foo() {
      setBackground(BACKGROUND);
      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
      addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
      g2.setStroke(STROKE);
      for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangleList) {
         g2.setColor(FILL_COLOR);
         g2.fill(rectangle);
         g2.setColor(DRAW_COLOR);
         g2.draw(rectangle);
      }
      g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
      if (pressPoint != null && dragPoint != null) {
         g2.setColor(FILL_COLOR.darker());
         int x = Math.min(pressPoint.x, dragPoint.x);
         int y = Math.min(pressPoint.y, dragPoint.y);
         int width = Math.abs(pressPoint.x - dragPoint.x);
         int height = Math.abs(pressPoint.y - dragPoint.y);
         g2.drawRect(x, y, width, height);
      }
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         pressPoint = e.getPoint();
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         dragPoint = e.getPoint();
         repaint();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         dragPoint = e.getPoint();
         int x = Math.min(pressPoint.x, dragPoint.x);
         int y = Math.min(pressPoint.y, dragPoint.y);
         int width = Math.abs(pressPoint.x - dragPoint.x);
         int height = Math.abs(pressPoint.y - dragPoint.y);
         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
         rectangleList.add(rect);

         pressPoint = null;
         dragPoint = null;
         repaint();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Foo());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of not using arrays and using arrayLists, but that does indeed do what the code is supposed to. I will have to tinker with it, but thank you very much for the help!